# I'm trying to update my database with java . i'm working in netbeans , there no error in the code but still the rows are not updated

Tags: java

I'm trying to update my database with java. I'm working in Netbeans, there is no error in the code but still, the rows are not updated.

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

            try{
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
          }
          catch(ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error in connectivity" );

          }
            try{

               String m11 = jTextField1.getText();
      String m22 = jTextField2.getText();
         com.mysql.jdbc.Connection conn = (com.mysql.jdbc.Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/inventorysystem","root","root123");
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         int bp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"Do you want to update the record ?");
         if(bp == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            String query = "update inventorycatalogmap set inventorycatalogname = '"+m11+"' and ProductCatalog='"+m22+"' where inventorycatalogname='"+m11+"';";
        stmt.execute(query);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Record has been updated");
         }
         if(bp == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
             NewFrame2 t = new NewFrame2();
             t.dispose(); 
             t.setVisible(true); 
         }
          if(bp == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
             NewFrame2 i = new NewFrame2();
              i.dispose(); 
             i.setVisible(true); 
         }
         stmt.close();
         conn.close();

          }
          catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Entry","message",2); 
          }
        }
```

Can anyone suggest, what went wrong in my implementation?

Comment: You are updating caterogy name with the same name, SO its updated, but you will not see any changes

Comment: I agree with you @sForSujit but you can see the changes of `ProductCatalog` :)

Comment: @YCF_L Yeah, Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

You are missing  conn.commit();

```
stmt.close();
 conn.commit();
 conn.close();
```

And probably your connection's auto-commit is not set true.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is open to syntax error and SQL Injection instead you have to use `PreparedStatement` it is more secure and more helpful :

```
String query = "update inventorycatalogmap set inventorycatalogname = ?, ProductCatalog=? where inventorycatalogname=?";
try (PreparedStatement update = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
    update.setString(1, m11);
    update.setString(2, m22);
    update.setString(3, m11);
    update.executeUpdate();
}
```

---

You have an error in your query :

```
set inventorycatalogname = '" + m11 + "' and ProductCatalog='" + m22 + "' where 
//---------------------------------------^^^
```

Also you should not use `and` when you set many fields you have to separate them just with `,`

Comment: Yeah, there must be comma instead of and keyword

Comment: exactly @sForSujit ;)